# C - Changing a string seems to change unrelated strings in the same way (CS50)

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    string keyupper = argv[1];
    string keylower = argv[1];


    if (argc != 2) //makes sure there is exactly 2 arguments (the program executable and the key)
    {
        printf("Please input a key.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if (strlen(key) != 26) //makes sure the key is exactly 26 letters
    {
        printf("Please make sure the key is 26 unique letters.\n");
        return 1;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //the loop to make the uppercase key
    {
        keyupper[i] = toupper(keyupper[i]);
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //the loop to make the lowercase key
    {
        keylower[i] = tolower(keylower[i]);
    }
```

Essentially, I want to make a very basic encryption using a key entered while executing the program, it needs to contain 26 unique letters. I want to create two arrays, an uppercase and a lowercase one, to make everything else much easier for me, but when running this code, all keys become either uppercase or lowercase depending on which loop is created last (in this case, they all become lowercase). Even `key` gets changed to lowercase even though it's used only once as a declaration. Everything else works but this.

This is for the CS50 course so functions such as `toupper()` are included in libraries.

This is my first ever question so sorry if it's worded poorly. Thank you!

Comment: They aren't unrelated strings: the three variables all point to the same string. The `string key = argv[1];` doesn't create a new string, only a copy of the pointer. You would need, for example, `string key = strdup(argv[1]);`

Comment: If you look at the typedef for `string` you'll see it's a pointer. It doesn't contain a copy of the data it points to. All of your pointers point to the same block of data. If you need a copy of the data to be able to change it and leave the original intact then make a copy.

Comment: @WeatherVane This makes a lot of sense, but why does it just create a pointer and not a new variable? I want to make sure I fully understand when I'm creating a pointer and when I'm creating a new string.

Comment: C doesn't have a native string type, only null-terminated `char` arrays. CS50 provides the `string` type as an abbreviation for `char*`. You can't copy arrays like that using simple assignment; as Weather Vane says, you need to call a function like `strdup`. (CS50 *may* have other stuff to copy/assign such strings - I don't really know.)

Comment: It *is* a new variable, but the type is a pointer comprising of 4 or perhaps 8 bytes. It isn't an array, which is what a C string actually is (and NUL-terminated). CS50 tries to be helpful by defining `string` as a pointer, but it isn't really a C string. It uses the name `string` for an object that isn't actually a string, but a pointer to one, and an array and pointer aren't the same thing. Same for the program arguments `char *argv[]`. That is a an array of pointers to strings (not an array of strings), and the actual strings being pointed to are in the framework that calls `main()`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I think I understand it about as much as I ever will and now I know what to do.

Comment: Yet again, cs50's dreadful attempt at hiding basic pointer types like `char *` in typedef aliases comes back to to bite an unsuspecting  beginner on the arse. Had all three of those vars been `char *` instead of `string`, and the arguments to `main` included `char *argv[]` rather than `string argv[]`,  the problem would have been *much* more glaring.  Pointers are used *everywhere* in C, and trust me, C engineers want to see those `*` 's. It is a giant, waving flag announcing "this is a pointer to something". Embrace that, and don't hide pointer types in aliases like cs50 does.

Comment: @WhozCraig Am I understanding correctly that ```string``` is exactly the same as ```char *```, and that ```char *``` means it is a pointer and not its own variable?

Comment: @Nizz You don't understand correctly. A pointer *is* a variable. It is variable whose value is an *address*. Just as a `int` holds an integer, a `float` holds a floating point value, and a `char` holds a character value, so too goes a pointer; they hold addresses. `int a; int *p = &a;` declares *two* variables; an `int` var and a pointer-to-`int` var.  cs50's header hides a pointer type behind an alias `string`, which makes it *less* obvious that all your code was doing was replicating the same *address* into three different pointer variables, all of whom thereafter pointed to the *same data*.

Comment: There are arguably two legitimate reasons to hide pointer types in typedef aliases: black-box "handle" APIs (nearly all such APIs manage their functionality via seemingly magic "handles" that are, in fact, pointers to data somewhere), and callback function prototypes. *Neither* of those are in-play in nearly all code. As you've seen, hiding pointer types in aliases like `string` make it *harder*, not easier, to really understand what is going on without having to peel back the layer and find the type alias that never should have been there to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

**Code failed to copy the *string* contents**

[Talking about *string* here, not the type `string`]

In C, a *string* is "... is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Code only copied pointers and not the *string* contents.

```
string key = argv[1];
string keyupper = argv[1];
string keylower = argv[1];
```

Comment discussion indicates OP now sees why code is in error.

**Repaired code**

```
//#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Avoid naked magic numbers, instead define them
#define KEY_N 26

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Do not code argv[1] until after argc check
    // string key = argv[1];
    // string keyupper = argv[1];
    // string keylower = argv[1];

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please input a key.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *key = argv[1];
    // else if (strlen(key) != 26)letters
    if (strlen(key) != KEY_N) {
        printf("Please make sure the key is 26 unique letters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char keyupper[KEY_N + 1];
    char keylower[KEY_N + 1];

    // for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < KEY_N; i++) {
        // keyupper[i] = toupper(keyupper[i]);
        keyupper[i] = toupper((unsigned char) key[i]);
    }
    keyupper[KEY_N] = '\0';
    ...
```

Comment: @nielsen Yes.  Code amended - also to handle negative `char`.